# Display a Boolean field result if it's True

Tags: django, django-templates, boolean, templatetags

I'm having trouble here to display the return of a boolean field in the template. I need to display the name of the field if it is true in the template. Any help will be welcome.

**models**

´´´
class IEIS(Model.models):
topo = models.BooleanField()
´´´

**views**

```
def view_ieis(request, pk):
    ieis = IEIS.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'ieis/view.html', {'ieis': ieis,})
```

**template.html**

```
<div table class="table table-reponsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th scope="col">Tipo</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>
                    {% if topo is True %}
                        <p>Topo</p>
                    {% endif %}

           </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed an `IEIS` object as `ieis` to the template, so that means you can check the boolean content of that object with:

```django
{% if ieis.topo %}
    <p>Topo</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Right. Thank you for your help, Willem.